# Disqus Comments affecting my pagespeed. How can I either lazy load or click to show comments?

Tags: pagespeed, disqus

Hi I've static website(made with Hugo) with Disqus installed. My website load time is really affected by ~30% in negative. So, I wish I could prevent it from loading it until a person reaches to that section or a better approach is that there'll be 'show comments' button that totally leave on visitor to decide.

I'm already using lazyload(lozad js library) but it's not working with disqus even I tried following code too

```
var iframes = doc.querySelectorAll('iframe');

iframes.forEach(function (e){

  e.classList.add('lozad'); // adds required 'lozad' class
  var iframeAttr = e.getAttribute('src'); 
  e.setAttribute('data-src', iframeAttr); // lozad needs source data in data-src attribute
  e.setAttribute('src', ''); // empty src attribute so that library use it at right time
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zachary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11499871/zwbetz) wrote a tutorial for Hugo sites on how to display a **Show comments** button and have the Disqus comments only displayed when a reader click on the button.

As a bonus, the Disqus Javascript file *embed.js* will only load when the button is clicked.

To add this to your site, first, create a partial and name it **disqus.html**. Inside this file, put the following code:

```html
<div id="disqus-container">
  {{ with .Site.DisqusShortname }}
    <button id="disqus-button" onclick="showComments()">Show comments</button>
    <div id="disqus-comments">
      {{ $isDummyName := eq . "yourdiscussshortname" }}
      {{ $isServer := $.Site.IsServer }}
      {{ if or $isDummyName $isServer }}
        <p>Disqus comments are disabled.</p>
        <script type="application/javascript">
          function showComments() {
            {{ partial "disqus-js-common.js" . | safeJS }}
          }
        </script>
      {{ else }}
        <div id="disqus_thread">
        </div>
        <script type="application/javascript">
          function showComments() {
            {{ partial "disqus-js-main.js" . | safeJS }}
            {{ partial "disqus-js-common.js" . | safeJS }}
          }
        </script>
      {{ end }}
      <noscript>Enable JavaScript to view Disqus comments.</noscript>
    </div>
  {{ end }}
</div>
```

Then, create two Javascript files. First one call it **disqus-js-common.js**. Inside this file, add the following code:

```js
// Remove button
var disqusButton = document.getElementById('disqus-button');
disqusButton.parentNode.removeChild(disqusButton); 
// Un-hide comments
var disqusComments = document.getElementById('disqus-comments');
disqusComments.style.display = 'block';
```

The second Javascript file call it **disqus-js-main.js**. And inside this one, add the following code:

```js
// Config
var disqus_config = function () {
};
// Build and append comments 
var d = document;
var s = d.createElement('script');
s.async = true;
s.src = '//' + "{{ . }}" + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', + new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
```

Finally, add a little bit of CSS to make everything looks better:

```css
#disqus-container {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
#disqus-button {
  width: 100%;
}
#disqus-comments {
  display: none; 
}
#disqus-comments,
#disqus-comments iframe {
  max-height: 65vh !important;
  overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

[Source](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/button-to-show-disqus-comments/17418?u=music47ell)

Comment: too late I know. but this way we're avoiding Hugo's built-in disqus template. I already knew this way of installing disqus commenting but found no solution for Hugo's template

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IntersectionObserver API to lazily load & initialize Disqus only once a user scrolls to a particular part of the page. The IO API is well-supported in modern browsers, so you wouldn't need to load any other lazy loading package (or custom JS) that'd further bog down your site.

Here's an example I got working. It uses the `div` that Disqus uses to mount its comments to as the point on the page that triggers everything to load & initialize. Note that a good chunk of this (it's commented) is copied straight from their documentation.

```
<script>
  let mountNode = document.querySelector("#disqus_thread");
  let options = {
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0,
  };

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        console.log("Initialize Disqus!");

        //-- Copied from their documentation: START

        var disqus_config = function () {
          this.page.url = "https://whatever.com";
          this.page.identifier = "whatever!";
        };

        var d = document,
          s = d.createElement("script");
        s.src = "https://your-shortname.disqus.com/embed.js";

        s.setAttribute("data-timestamp", +new Date());
        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);

        //-- Copied from their documentation: END

        // After initializing, we don't need this observer anymore.
        observer.unobserve(mountNode);
        return;
      }
    });
  }, options);

  observer.observe(mountNode);
</script>
```

All that said, even this sort of approach is gonna get you so far. Building comments and a form client-side is an inherently expensive set of tasks, and so you're still gonna see some detrimental effects to page performance. If not load time, then the blocking of the main thread by all that Disqus is executing on the page when it starts up. You're also gonna miss out on the SEO benefit of having status HTML comments on your page.

All of this represents the bulk of the reasons I ditched disqus on my own site and built my own service for it, which I eventually opened up to the public. It integrates with different platforms (not yet Hugo, but it's down the road hopefully), and spits out statically-rendered comments and avoides the-side bloat, etc. Keep it in mind for any future rebuild you go through:

https://jamcomments.com/

Comment: I've thought enough/got enough questions about this to warrant writing it up in a blog post:

https://www.macarthur.me/posts/lazy-load-disqus

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with pure HTML and JavaScript

But since I really like Alpine.js this is how it can be done

```
<button
  x-data="disqusComponent()"
  x-show="!loaded"
  @click="toggle()"
>Show/Post Comments
</button>

<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

See [Load Disqus Comments on demand](https://lunadxp.com/article/load-disqus-comments-demand)